# How to add Key frames to the compositing nodes?

Tags: keyframes

[image]I have been following the 'Old TV intro' tutorial by the youtuber Blender Education and at watermark 28:40 he adds a keyframe to the offset on the x axis in a texture node. I am using 2.81 and I cannot seem to understand how he did it, although in the tutorial he used an older version of blender. Any help or answers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As you can see in the screenshot above he enters some shortcut that creates a keyframe on the offset section of the texture node. What I'm trying to find out is how that is achieved in blender 2.81. Sorry for any previous confusion.

Comment: Wow I was being so stupid! Yeah it works when you just hover over the function, thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do keyframes has not changed. Hover the cursor over the item you want to keyframe and press the <kbd>I</kbd> key (I as in "Insert keyframe")

Or right click on the item and select add keyframe from the menu.